# What are the brick numbers of the bricks circled in this image?

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands

[image: screenshot of a youtube video titled: LEGO Technic RC 4x4 mini Buggy Building Instructions ft. BuWizz & RC Buggy Motor! The image shows several groups of blocks from the set circled]

What are the brick numbers of the ones circled in this image?

Answer (score 21):

LEGO items:

- [Technic, Axle 3L with Stud](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6587#T=C) (6587, 13670)
- [Technic, Liftarm Thin 1 x 2 - Axle Holes](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=41677#T=C) (41677, 44862)
- [Technic, Liftarm Thin 1 x 6](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32063#T=C) (32063, 28570)
- [Technic, Steering Arm 6 x 2 with Tow Ball Socket Rounded, Chamfered](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=57515#T=C) (57515)
- [Electric, Motor RC Race Buggy](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=5292#T=C) (5292)
- [Electric, Motor 9V Power Functions Servo with Dark Bluish Gray Bottom](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=99498c01#T=C) (99498c01)

Non-LEGO item:

- [BuWizz](https://buwizz.com)

Comment: Incidentally, BuWizz also makes a Buggy Motor replacement which is probably cheaper than an official one.

Comment: ok thanks for you update